# Counting the number of cells with a certain numerical pattern

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following is what I want to do and I think it could be tricky.

I have a column with a list of percentages based on

```
    =IFERROR(CONCATENATE(ROUND(100*[@[Calls Offered]]/([@[Calls Forecasted]]*1.05),1),"-",ROUND    (100*[@[Calls
Offered]]/([@[Calls Forecasted]]*0.95),1),"%"),"N/A")
```

the first cell ended up being `99.6 - 110.1%`

To decide if the forecast is effective the actual value must be between .95 and 1.05 of the forecast, so percentage wise, the left number must be less than 100 % and the right number must be greater than 100%.
So the first cell satisfies this situation.

What I want to do is to count how many of these cells in the column would satisfy this.

I have a feeling that it would be easier to split the forecast variance into two sets so that I can check each columns that way, but it is important that these numbers are on the same sell, for visual purpose.

I think this could be tricky because what I tried to do first is to show the percentages using "concat" but I could not change the formatting of the number into a percentage for some reason.  So, I forced in a % symbol within the function so that it looks nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data starting in column A at row 2, this should calculate the over/under.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("žžž",A:A )), " ", REPT(" ", 9)), 9)<100)*
            (--RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("žžž",A:A )), " ", REPT(" ", 9)), 9)>1))
```

[image: over_under]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it okay if you could explain a little?  I am a beginner at excel and I know none of the functions used, just to get me started.

Comment: Have you been through the the [Evaluate Formula](https://goo.gl/Vl25be) command (repeat if necessary) and have a specific question? I'm sorry but I do not have plans to write a treatise on every operation and function in that formula.

Comment: @Jeeped - Marvelous, you are tricking excel into doing things in non conventional ways. So much to learn from you. Using substitute-rept to get left and right out of the string is super. What I still can't understand is how does index return range reference instead of value at row 7?

Comment: @PankajR - The [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) actually returns a valid range reference; you **see** the value from a lookup much like you would see the value in a cell with `=A1` in it. This is not the same with the [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) which only returns a value. In fact, you can even put two INDEX functions together; e.g. for `SUM(B3:B10)` like `SUM(INDEX(B:B, 3):INDEX(B:B, 10))`. This functionality allows you avoid INDIRECT and OFFSET.

Comment: Thanks. that was helpful

Comment: I see, that is okay.  I'm sure if I took my time observing what each functions do I would be able to figure out what is going on.